# Treble notification of earning a "yearling" badge

Tags: bug, badges

I wonder why the notification of my earning a "yearling" badge came in triplicate (three identical notifications). I haven't seen this type of behaviour before on StackExchange.

This is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the notification]

Answer (score 3):

If look closely at the logo for the site associated with the badge, you will notice that it is grey, and thus does not refer to Academia, but to Academia Meta:

[image]

This is also reflected on your [meta profile](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10691/user10691?tab=activity&sort=all).
So apparently, your account on Meta was only “woke up” yesterday, but since its reputation and creation date is taken from your main account, you became eligible for there Yearling badges at this moment.

It is normal that you gain Yearling badges for your Meta account the same time as your main account even if you have no Meta activity whatsoever. However, this leaves the interesting question why this did not happen before for you – to which I have no answer.

Comment: So it appears that I was awarded three badges for an account—Academia Meta—to which I have never provided any input (prior to the present enquiry)! Why this happened at all is just as puzzling to me as why it happened yesterday.

Comment: @user10691: See my edit.

Comment: When I looked further at my Academia profile, I noticed that the "yearling" badge is described as (and looks) silver. This interpretation of the colour may be more appropriate than "grey for Meta". At least there was some activity, over a period of years, on the primary Academia site that might justify such an award—if not its timing and multiplicity.

Comment: @user10691: See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.